# Img scraping using bs4 and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some img files from IG using selenium and bs4. I have this following script to do it, it seems to work fine, but eventually I'd like it to just print `img src`, a sample: `https://scontent-lax3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/2592f6b07f88bfc4bfdf6d73400a04b8/5BA6E998/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/28752330_1972627949433283_1816022201220988928_n.jpg` and download images later. But for now I would need some help to just print that img src link without the tags and extras. Thanks for the advice.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

url = ('https://www.instagram.com/kitties/')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

img_url = soup.find_all('img', class_='_2di5p')

print img_url
```

Comment: what does it do now?

Comment: it prints all the html tags and dimensions etc @pydude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print out the `src` of the found images.

```
imgs= soup.find_all('img', class_='_2di5p')
for img in imgs:
    img_url=img["src"]
    print img_url
```

Comment: Hell yes, that was it. Totally forgot I can do it this way. Thanks! Vote up @pydude